# Issue returning images over web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am having a weird issue returning an image via web api, I do this in several places in my application without fail but this one is causing me issues, any help would be greatly appreciates.

This works

```
  Bitmap bitmap = getImage();
        MemoryStream bitmapStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save("C:\\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            if (Request.Headers.IfModifiedSince.HasValue)
            {
                // The file has not been modified since the browser cached it.
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream("C:\\test.png", FileMode.Open));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
```

while this does not

```
 Bitmap bitmap = getImage();
        MemoryStream bitmapStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(bitmapStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            if (Request.Headers.IfModifiedSince.HasValue)
            {
                // The file has not been modified since the browser cached it.
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(bitmapStream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
```

I really need to do this in memory and not save a temp file to drive, but for some reason when I do it in memory the result is an empty file 0 bytes, I do try to set the content length manually but then the file doesnt download at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to reset the position of the stream after the save happens.

`bitmapStream.Position = 0`;